# toolbar is not displaying on activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-styles

I'm adding toolbar to an activity that has setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled the toolbar is not displayed at all but when i tap where back button is located its working but toolbar is not displayed at all like toolbar's background color and title is not displaying instead its showing part of activity laying there

here is how I'm enabling toolbar in activity:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white);

    toolbarTitle.setText(env.appLoginLogin);
    toolbarTitle.setTypeface(vrFont);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

the xml:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ablayoutsignup"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/signup_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/mainbg"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.97"
    android:background="@color/onboarding_bg_overlay3"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/hah_logo"
    android:id="@+id/iv_hah"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/iv_hah"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/emergencyVideo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/pw"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/whiteThree"
            android:background="@drawable/line_edit_text"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTwo"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:autoText="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/email_error"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email_error"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line_edit_text"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/pw_layout">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pw"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/whiteThree"
                android:textColor="@color/whiteTwo"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/padlock"
                android:drawablePadding="26dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_pw_show"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pw"
                android:text="text"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="error"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/pw_error"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pw_layout"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_create_account"
            android:textColor="@color/warmGrey"
            android:layout_below="@id/pw_error"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_create_account"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/terms">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_terms"
                android:textColor="@color/warmGrey" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/termsConditionsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/greyishBrown"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/terms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@drawable/bordered_button_green"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Sign up"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/loginBtntxt"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/donthaveacc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTwo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:text="Already have an Account? "/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/donthaveacc"
                android:text="Login"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/line"
                android:textColor="@color/whiteTwo"
                android:id="@+id/tv_signup" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign up with"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loginBtntxt"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/tv_continue"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/social_media"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_continue"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fbx"
            android:id="@+id/btn_fb_login"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/googlex"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_fb_login"
            android:id="@+id/iv_google"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emergencyVideo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/line"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ablayoutlogin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_container"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ablayoutsignup"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progress" />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/progress"/>
```

style on activity in manifest:

```
 <style name="ThemeLogin" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#292E37</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post your whole XMl

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: no just toolbar is not displaying but controls on it are working @Heisen-Berg

Comment: @ADM added xml in question

Comment: The root is still missing in xml.

Comment: @ADM added root

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

and

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("text here");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are very seldom helpful. Please explain the change you have made compared to the OP’s code and in particular: how it helps,

Answer (score 0):

you can try making these changes..

```
  <style name="ThemeLogin" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#292E37</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

and here

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ablayoutsignup"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signup_toolbar_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ablayoutsignup"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/signup_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/ablayoutsignup"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
// Rest of content goes here

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the toolbar is there and its back button is there working(but not displaying), but toolbar is not displaying

Comment: Thats because it hides under Other views . This is How `RelativeLayout' works . One suggestion go with CoordinateLayout . There is lots of examples on web . Why take much headache. Thx

Comment: Because your overlay views are not clickable .If you make imageView clickable which is `match_parent' the back button won't work. try to test it .

Comment: trying with toolbar.bringtofront